# How to nullify key temporarily when another key is pressed in AutoHotKey?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, gaming

I am playing a rhythm game where you can bind two keys to hit one note (in my case LShift and LControl), however it will only register the note if it is being hit singularly. By that, I mean if I have LShift pressed down, it will hold that note, but if I press LControl while LShift is being pressed down, it will not register a second note press, instead it will continue to hold the first note press. 
What I am asking for is an AutoHotKey script that will nullify the key press when the other key is being pressed i.e. If LShift is held down, pressing LControl will nullify LShift and press LControl.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
LShift::
    if(GetKeyState("LControl")) {
        Send, {LControl up}
    }
    Send, {LShift down}
return

LShift up::
    if(GetKeyState("LShift")) {
        Send, {LShift up}
    }
return

LControl::
    if(GetKeyState("LShift")) {
        Send, {LShift up}
    }
    Send, {LControl down}
return

LControl up::
    if(GetKeyState("LControl")) {
        Send, {LControl up}
    }
return
```

I don't know if you necessarily need the `up` hotkeys, but I think this will make your script more consistent. If you don't need the keys to be held down at all, you could also just remap the respective key to be sent once (resulting in a quasi simultaneous down/up event).

**P.S.:**
Is the behavior of your game a bug or a feature? In other words: Could it be that it deliberately doesn't accept new keys while the other is being held down? If that's the case, you're principally trying to cheat ;)